# Memory leak in CoreGraphics while switching sprite texture. Code inside

Tags: memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone, core-graphics, ccsprite, cgcontextref

EDIT: I tried using the push/pop thing, but now it crashes.

I have a feeling what I'm attempting to do is way off.. Is there any way to just get core graphics showing up on the screen? I need something thats able to be updated every frame, like drawing a line between two points that always move around..
Even if someone knows of a complete alternative Ill try it.

in .h

```
CGContextRef context;
```

in .m

in init method

```
int width = 100;
int height = 100;

void *buffer = calloc(1, width * height * 4);
context = CreateBitmapContextWithData(width, height, buffer);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1);
CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

hud_sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:image key:@"hud_image1"];

free(buffer);
free(image);

hud_sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
hud_sprite.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);

[self addChild:hud_sprite z:100];
```

in a method I call when I want to update it.

```
int width = 100;
int height = 100;

UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)); //<-- crashes here. bad access...

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, random_float(0, 1),random_float(0, 1),random_float(0, 1), .8);
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height));
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

UIGraphicsPopContext();

//CGContextRelease(ctx);

[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTextureForKey:@"hud_image1"];
[hud_sprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addCGImage:image forKey:@"hud_image1"]];

free(image);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `UIGraphicsPushContext(context)`.  You must balance this with `UIGraphicsPopContext()`.  Since you're not calling `UIGraphicsPopContext()`, you are leaving `context` on UIKit's graphics context stack, so it never gets deallocated.

Also, you are calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, which creates a new graphics context that you later release (correctly) by calling `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`.  But you never use this context.  You would access the context by calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`, but you never call that.

#### UPDATE

**Never call `free` on a Core Foundation object!**

You are getting a `CGImage` (which is a Core Foundation object) with this statement:

```
CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
```

Then later you are calling `free` on it:

```
free(image);
```

You must **never** do that.

Go read the [*Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH).  When you are done with a Core Foundation object, and you have ownership of it (because you got it from a Create function or a Copy function), you must release it with a Release function.  In this case you can use either `CFRelease` or `CGImageRelease`:

```
CGImageRelease(image);
```

Furthermore, you are allocating `buffer` using `calloc`, then passing it to `CreateBitmapContextWithData` (which I guess is your wrapper for `CGBitmapContextCreateWithData`), and then freeing `buffer`.  But `context` keeps a pointer to the buffer.  So after you `free(buffer)`, `context` has a dangling pointer.  That's why you're crashing.  You cannot free `buffer` until after you have released `context`.

The best way to handle this is to let `CGBitmapContextCreateWithData` take care of allocating the buffer itself by passing `NULL` as the first (`data`) argument.  There is no reason to allocate the buffer yourself in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, but now I am running into more problems.. I edited the post with all the relevant code.

Comment: Ok, everything works flawlessly now, thanks so much. and I will read that document... I come from a basic language where memory is handled way more for you so allot is new... anyways, thanks again. I was using free allot of places for my one time created graphics as well.. and I see sending NULL thru the create context method makes allot more sense.. thanks for that! :D